# Programmatically define the Endpoint and Binding

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

Warping the call of a web service in a Class Library, I had to past the endpoint definition from app.config to other project that was using the Library.

In order to get rid of that I try to translate my app.config setting into explicit in order to pass Binding and Endpoint definition to the ClientBase.

```
var client = new myServiceClient(customBinding, custonEndpoint);
```

I'm looking for a way to translate system.serviceModel definition into code.
And the simpliest definition is giving me issue. For example with the following configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="NetTcpBinding_MyService" />
        </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://address:port/Foo/Services/MyService"
            binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_MyService"
            contract="MyService.MyService" name="NetTcpBinding_MyService">
            <identity>
                <userPrincipalName value="FooBar@SecondLevel.TopLevel" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I find no property that match those parameter in `NetTcpBinding` neither in the Security property:

```
var endPoint = new EndpointAddress(__EndPoint);
var binding = new NetTcpBinding();
binding.Name = "";
```

Resulting in an error SSPI.